# Can't login to .htpasswd protected directory created with ansible

Tags: ansible, .htpasswd

I am trying to use ansible to create .haccess and .htpasswd files

```
htpasswd: path=/mypath/.htpasswd name=test password=test owner=root group=root mode=0640
```

But I can't login with the test:test credentials

The value inside the file does seem valid and has correctly used the APR MD5 algorithm

```
test:$apr1$i7i0IUWn$YwAufYj/eBdNPxFdZ7sYX0
```

I'm using ansible 1.7.2, the host machine is Centos 6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
htpasswd: path=/mypath/.htpasswd name=test password=test owner=root group=root mode=0640
```

This creates a htpasswd file that is read/writeable by `root`, readable by users in the `root` group (which is only `root`), and not readable by the world.

Assuming you are running apache as user `apache` and there's an `apache` group, this is what you want:

```
htpasswd: path=/mypath/.htpasswd name=test password=test owner=apache group=apache mode=0640
```

You could actually lock it down to be a little bit safer, since `apache` only needs to read the file, not write it:

```
htpasswd: path=/mypath/.htpasswd name=test password=test owner=root group=apache mode=0640
```

Comment: Indeed this was the correct solution: the group needed to be set to "apache". Thanks!